# Selecting a style parameter with jquery .attr

Tags: jquery, attr

I have the following code:

```
alert($("div", data).attr("style.background"));
```

I would like to select the colour value on this code:

```
<div id = "test"style="font-family: serif; font-size: x-large; font-weight: bold; background: #5e5; text-align: center; margin: 0px; padding: 16px;">
```

I am unsure what to use instead of `style.background`.

Any help would be amazing, thanks!

Edit:

More Code

```
 success: function (data) {

                    alert(data);
                    alert($("div", data).css("background"));



                },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for why your jQuery selector `$('div',data)` isn't working, that's because `data` is a string, not a jQuery object. To get what you want, you need to do:

```
 $(data).filter('div')
```

This will get you the `div` contained within the `data` string.

If all you want is the color, try:

```
$(data).filter('div').css('backgroundColor')
```

However, this will return the color in `rgb(...)` format, as jQuery converts all color codes to rgb.

However, if you want the actual value used in the `style` attribute, you'll need to parse the attribute itself to find your answer:

```
var style = $(data).filter('div').attr('style');
var styleObj = {};
$.each(style.split(';'),function(){
    var rule = this.split(':');
    styleObj[$.trim(rule[0])] = $.trim(rule[1]);
});


alert(styleObj.background) // "#e55"
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/wN87m/)

Comment: I've updated my jsFiddle demo to use a string as its source, as you're doing in your code

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) instead of `attr()`:

```
 alert($("div", data).css("background"));
```

To get only color you need to pass `background-color` instead of `background`. This will be working with other CSS properties too.

Comment: I am still receiving 'undefined' in the alert box.

Comment: doing `"background"` will also return positioning and repeat values

Comment: @JamesMclaren What is `data` in your example? Without it everything works fine, look demo: http://jsfiddle.net/antyrat/LPhcK/

Comment: The data is the entire html file which I display in an alert.

Comment: Maybe this caused `undefined`? Have you see my demo? See updated with background-color only http://jsfiddle.net/antyrat/LPhcK/1/

Comment: I seen your example yes. Will be useful for other things too.I added more to OP.

Comment: @JamesMclaren there is a lot of tutorials to convert grb->hex https://www.google.com/search?q=rgb+to+hex+conversion